# Cannot call method on nvarchar - no nvarchar in db - trying to parameterize table names

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I'm trying to query my database to show relevant information and it was working up until I started using parameters. Now it's telling me I can't call a method on nvarchar and I can't figure out the problem.

I was trying to figure out if it's an error when I do something like this:

```
@Parameter.customer_id
```

But I wasn't sure.

Here is my query line:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select Customer.customer_id, Customer.customer_name," +  
                  "@Product.license_start_date, " + p + ".version, " + p + "Details.processor " + 
                  "from Customer " + 
                  "left outer join " + p + 
                  " on Customer.customer_id = " + p + ".customer_id" + 
                  "left outer join " + p + "Details " +
                  "  on " + p + ".customer_id = " + p + "Details.customer_id";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product", ddProducts.SelectedItem.Text);
```

I used + p + just to make sure that the query was functioning and now I'm trying to get it to work with the parameters

Also a side question, I have tables that would be @Product+Details (e.g Computer, ComputerDetails). I want to make it so I can do something like + Product + "Details". Can I do that like this:

```
@Product Details
```

Or do I have to have a special parameter for that?

Comment: I am not sure to have understand your question, but remember that a parameter cannot be used to pass a column name or a table name.

Comment: You can't do that using parameters, as simple as that :) And to be fair, even having to try is an indicator of trouble with your design. You want to pick a table based on what you've got selected in a drop down? That just screams "abuse".

Comment: I think you cannot use parameters for object names.

Comment: So there's nothing insecure about this then and parameters only really make it safer when it's a variable? @Luaan only people who have access can use it, it's not public

Comment: Oh, it's very insecure. It's just that you can't fix the security hole by using parameters :)

Comment: I see lol, thanks for the tips though.

Comment: If you really need to dinamically pass the table name then be sure to not allow your users to type it. Create a DropDown from the TABLES listed in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA view an select the table from the predefined names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how you use parameter to address security.
You app should know what tables and what columns.

Yes you can use .NET variables for table and column names to build up a statement dynamically but that variable should NEVER be user direct input (they get to key in the table name).

You may have a pull down of used versus new where you build up a query and insert the table name of tableNew or tableUsed.    But you can't use a parameter for that.

All the parameter are datatypes.  (there is no column or table datatype)
[SqlDbType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Lets say the user gets to enter a part description.
That is something you should never pass directly to TSQL.
You put that in a parameter so the user cannot do bad things.

```
string commandText = "UPDATE Sales.Store SET Demographics = @demographics "
    + "WHERE CustomerID = @ID;";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;

    // Use AddWithValue to assign Demographics. 
    // SQL Server will implicitly convert strings into XML.
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@demographics", demoXml);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```